# Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint, It works in ssms but not in vs

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a procedure that when called in SQL doesn't have a problem, but when I try to execute it from code directly using FromSqlRaw() of EntityFrameworkCore with c#, I get this "Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint" Any Idea what might be causing this problem. Here is my stored procedure:

````
@IdentityId BIGINT,
@Year INT,
@Week INT

AS 

BEGIN 

    SELECT IdentityId, AccountCode, PostingTimestamp AS BookedDate, TransactionTimestamp AS ValueDate, BaseAmountEuro/100.00 AS AmountInEuro, TransactionType,
    ISNULL(t.Curr, ' N/A') as OriginalCurrency, t.Amount0 as OriginalCurrencyAmount
    FROM ccc.InvestmentTransactionStatistics its WITH (nolock) 
    left join MULCCC.ccc.TRANSACTIONS t WITH (nolock) on t.Num_Oper = its.TransactionRef 
    WHERE its.IdentityId = @IdentityId
    AND [Year]  = @Year AND Week = @Week
    AND ISNULL(its.InternalTransfer, 0) = 0
    UNION
    
    SELECT ms.IdentityId, ms.AccountCode, ms.TransactionTimestamp AS BookedDate, ms.TransactionTimestamp AS ValueDate, ms.BaseAmountEuro/100.00 AS AmountInEuro, ms.TransactionType, 
    CASE WHEN mr.FxDetails IS NULL Then 'EUR' 
         ELSE JSON_VALUE (mr.FxDetails,'$.FromCcy')
    END AS OriginalCurrency,
    CASE WHEN mr.FxDetails IS NULL Then ms.BaseAmountEuro/100.00
         ELSE JSON_VALUE (mr.FxDetails,'$.FromAmount')
    END AS OriginalCurrencyAmount
    FROM ccc.MBTransactionStatistics ms WITH (nolock) 
    LEFT JOIN ccc.MBTransactionRequests mr with(nolock) ON mr.MbUniqueTransactionReference = ms.TransactionRef 
    WHERE  ms.IdentityId  = @IdentityId
    AND [Year]  = @Year AND Week = @Week
    
END```
````

Comment: Maybe because of the system culture? (3,5 instead of 3.5 etc.)

Comment: You need to use parameters in the c# code.  The driver is guessing at the variable type and guessing wrong.  The c# driver is picking a String type instead of a BigInt.